# Disabling Set alarm programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, alarm

I set an alarm through my app in objective c for a particular time.
Is it possible to disable that alarm programmatically from the app ?

Comment: are you using localpush notification

Comment: Show us how you set the alarm in your app. I am not aware you can set an alarm for Apple's Clock app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are setting alarm through local notification, then you can cancel it by below code

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Comment: No I am setting direct alarm.